# Issue while importing react-table

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-table, tsx

I have next import:

```
import { useTable, useSortBy, useFilters, useColumnOrder } from 'react-table'
```

But I have next error:

```
Module '"react-table"' has no exported member 'useTable'.
```

The strange thing I have used it before in a previous project, and all worked fine, but in this project, it triggers an error.

Version: `"react-table": "^7.6.3"`

P.S. If I `npm i @types/react-table@7.0.29` I have much more errors.

What should I do?

Comment: For me its working fine. Try to reinstall the Package using "npm i react-table".

Comment: For me not working, started next project and it doesnt work

Comment: May be its due to typescript. Check the link once https://github.com/tannerlinsley/react-table/issues/1721

Comment: I had this same issue with react-table@7.8.0 and could fix it installing @types/react-table@7.7.18

Answer (score 0):

This is still happening in v8. Had a similar error and finally fixed it. I updated my typescript and now it's working with the following versions:

```
"@tanstack/react-table": "8.5.28",
"typescript": "4.8.4",
```

For Google SEO purposes, my errors were:

> ERROR in Component.tsx:7:3
>
> TS2305: Module
> '"../../../../node_modules/@tanstack/react-table/build/types"' has no
> exported member 'ColumnDef'.

> ERROR in src/Component.tsx:9:3
>
> TS2305: Module
> '"../../../../node_modules/@tanstack/react-table/build/types"' has no
> exported member 'getCoreRowModel'.

> ERROR in src/Component.tsx:10:3
>
> TS2305: Module
> '"../../../../node_modules/@tanstack/react-table/build/types"' has no
> exported member 'getSortedRowModel'

> ERROR in src/Component.tsx:11:3
>
> TS2305: Module
> '"../../../../node_modules/@tanstack/react-table/build/types"' has no
> exported member 'SortingState'.

Originally answered here: https://github.com/TanStack/table/issues/4459#issuecomment-1315189925

Comment: has this solution worked for any1 else ? I'm mentioning that i use react-table V7 and i'm having the same issue. The weird part is sometimes it works for no reason ....